# Rename (inbox/sent) folders in outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I had a Russian outlook 2007 , I've uninstalled it and installed English 2010, but the name of the folders are still in Russian, anybody knows hot fix that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try one of these commands on the command line:

If you installed the **64 bit** version  **on a 64 bit OS** or the **32 bit version** of Office **on a 32 bit OS**:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\Office14\Outlook.exe" /resetfoldernames
```

If you installed the **32 bit version** of Office **on a 64 bit OS**:

```
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Office\Office14\Outlook.exe" /resetfoldernames
```

I'm not totally sure if the folder structure is right. The important thing here is to launch Outlook with the "/resetfoldernames" switch.